# Virtual Host Server Setup

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

I have a server setup with 3 projects on it but running on different ports on ubuntu but same IP. This is a java application that is compiled with sbt tool and runs on ports

```
 x.x.x.x:7000
 x.x.x.x:7001
 x.x.x.x:7002
```

so I want to map a domain to these ports such that

```
 x.x.x.x:7000 => admin.domain.com
 x.x.x.x:7001 => users.domain.com
 x.x.x.x:7002 => domain2.com
```

I have apache2 installed and want to do virtual hosting with it. The problem is there is no document root as these projects are first compiled and served to the ports..

I have this

```
 <VirtualHost x.x.x.x:7000>    
          ServerAdmin admin@oneshoppoint.com
          ServerName  www.admin.oneshoppoint.com
       </VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
x.x.x.xmetadata.google.internal metadata
35.236.121.166:7000 admin.oneshoppoint.com

x.x.x.x yates.c.modified-badge-211108.internal yates  # Added by Google
x.x.x.xmetadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

Not working though, any suggestions?

Comment: Uhm, where is your reverse proxy definition ?

Comment: What is your /etc/hosts configuration?

Comment: @Marged Hw do I use that?

Comment: @FrancescoSimeoli I have updated the question and added it. kindly check

Comment: You can not specify a port in the hosts file

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /etc/hosts file and add the following lines (change x.x.x.x with the IP address):

> x.x.x.x           admin.domain.com
>
> x.x.x.x           users.domain.com
>
> x.x.x.x           domain2.com

Do not specify the port. In this way you create an association between the simboilc name and the IP adress.
The port must be specified in the virtual host. After change restart Apache.